# Kamtza bar Kamtza

Tags: history, tisha-bav, yerushalayim-jerusalem

This might be speculation, but during learning yesterday we discussed how would people have known if the cohenim brought the sacrifice with the blemish on its lips? Would Bar-Kamtza have found another way to cause trouble?

Also Zechariah's modesty lead to all this, so why did they listen?

Chabad translation: http://m.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/404863/jewish/Kamtza-and-Bar-Kamtza.htm

http://www.chabad.org/media/pdf/323/YIxQ3233957.pdf

TALMUD, GITTIN 55–56

Comment: Here is an interesting approach: http://allyourbeis.blogspot.co.il/2014/07/the-politics-of-kamtza-and-bar-kamtza.html

Comment: Some background to the question's premises, or sources thereof, could greatly improve the question's user-friendliness.

Comment: @Lee I posted from my phone don't have sources on hand. Feel free to update, or I'll try and do it later on a PC.

Comment: As @Lee noted, this question is very unclear without an indication of what story it refers to. I'm closing it as a temporary measure; please [edit] it so that more people can understand it and provide good answers, and then it can be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

According to Josephus, during this time Jerusalem was split between three factions fighting over the city and the legitimacy to rule in Jersualem, as well as how to deal with the Romans.

Presumably, one of the parties would have advertised the ordeal for political gain, as happens today where people go to the press to advertise some fault in their political opponents.

Comment: Hasn't his account of the whole incident been questioned? I suppose that makes sense though, were the cohenim split as well?

Comment: The details of his numbers have been questioned, but not his general account.  Yes, there were two sets of Cohanim. Tzadukim and Perushim. There was also the High Priest vs other Cohanim.  There were lots of factions.